# CSS Animation doesn't really stop

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working on a mobile first project, it's a project on with HTML and CSS only, allowing us to learn how to do animation with CSS only. I have a problem with my project that I hope you can help me with.

Due to the circle animation when you load the page, the button "Explorer nos restaurants" is not working, like the animation is still there and overlapping the page, I can't find a way to avoid this..

Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide to me!

```css
/* Barre de chargement */
.chargement {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: loader;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

.chargement_bloc {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.chargement_bloc-cercle {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px solid #fff;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    animation-name: circle;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}
@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    99% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(1500deg);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        background-color: #9356DC;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    99% {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #9356DC;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
/* + modifier media queries pc pour version feuille */

/* Header */
header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 4rem;
}

header h1 {
    font-family: 'Shrikhand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Localisation */

.localisation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 3px -9px #CCC;
}

.localisation i {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

/* Réservation */

.reservation {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.reservation h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.reservation p {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.reservation .btn {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-size: 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF79DA, #9356DC);
    background-position: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #0000002e;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.reservation .btn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    background-position: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<!--Meta-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ohmyfood - Page d'accueil</title>
<!--Link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accueil.css">
<!--FontAwesome--> 
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec6ba8c4d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Barre de chargement -->
    <div class="chargement">
        <div class="chargement_bloc">
            <div class="chargement_bloc-cercle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
    </header>
<!-- Localisation -->
    <main>
        <div class="localisation">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <p>Paris, Belleville</p>
        </div>
<!-- Réservation + Bouton -->
        <section class="reservation">
            <h2>Réservez le menu qui vous convient</h2>
            <p>Découvrez des restaurants d'exception, sélectionnés par nos soins.</p>
            <button class="btn" type="button" href="#restaurants">Explorer nos restaurants</button>
        </section>
```

Comment: I've tested in Chrome and Firefox. Your loading spinnner pops up for a couple of seconds then the page appears and the button state does change when I hover. Naturally the link itself doesn't work from Strack Overflow but from what I can see everything looks fine.

Comment: This is because your `loader` animation resets all values to their starting values, after it is finished. Add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to the `.chargement` class so that it remains on the last frame

```
.chargement {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: loader;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```